# Random number generator in a for loop gives same numbers each time

Tags: c++, for-loop, random

This program is supposed to function as a pretty primitive slot machine with three different "wheels" to spin. Each wheels contains a set amount of characters. A function generates a random number to assign as an array position in each wheel, which then yields a symbol corresponding to that position.

The problem I'm having is that the randomly generated number doesn't change through each iteration of my for loop. So I'm basically always getting "X - X" or " X @ -" for every single loop-through. I've searched through previously asked questions and found several related ones, but none seemed to solve my particular problem.

Apologies for the longish code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const int WHEEL_POSITIONS = 30;
const char wheelSymbols[WHEEL_POSITIONS + 1] = "-X-X-X-X-X=X=X=X*X*X*X*X@X@X7X";

struct slotMachine
{
    char symbols[WHEEL_POSITIONS + 1];
    int spinPos;
    char spinSymbol;
} wheels[3];

void startWheels(slotMachine []);
void spinWheels(slotMachine []);
void displayResults(slotMachine []);
bool getWinner(slotMachine []);

int main(void)
{
    int spinNum;

    cout << "How many times do you want to spin the wheel? ";
    cin >> spinNum;

    // Calls startWheels function
    startWheels(wheels);

    for (int i = 0; i < spinNum; i++)
    {
        // Calls spinWheels function
        spinWheels(wheels);

        // Calls displayResults function
        displayResults(wheels);

        // Calls function getWinner; if getWinner is true, outputs winning message
        if (getWinner(wheels) == true)
        {
            cout << "Winner! Matched 3 of " << wheels[0].spinSymbol << "." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}

// Function to initialize each wheel to the characters stored in wheelSymbols[]
void startWheels(slotMachine fwheels[3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (WHEEL_POSITIONS + 1); j++)
        {
            fwheels[i].symbols[j] = wheelSymbols[j];
        }
    }
}

// Function to generate a random position in each wheel
void spinWheels(slotMachine fwheels[3])
{
    time_t seed;

    time(&seed);
    srand(seed);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        fwheels[i].spinPos = (rand() % WHEEL_POSITIONS);
    }
}

void displayResults(slotMachine fwheels[3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        fwheels[i].spinSymbol = fwheels[i].symbols[(fwheels[i].spinPos)];
        cout << fwheels[i].spinSymbol;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

bool getWinner(slotMachine fwheels[3])
{
    if ((fwheels[0].spinSymbol == fwheels[1].spinSymbol) && (fwheels[0].spinSymbol == fwheels[2].spinSymbol) && (fwheels[1].spinSymbol == fwheels[2].spinSymbol))
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing, but I can't quite find it!

Comment: Did you try printing out the result of the call to rand() function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are re-seeding your random number generator every time you call the function `spinwheels`.

Move these three lines into the top of your `main` function.

```
   time_t seed;

   time(&seed);
   srand(seed);
```

When we generate random numbers using `rand()`, we are actually using a [pseudo-Random Number Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (PRNG), which generates a fixed sequence of random-looking values based on a particular input called a `seed`. When we set the seed, we are effectively resetting the the sequence to start at the same seed again.

You might think that using `time` would result in a different seed each time, which should still give you a different result each time, but in a fast computer program, so little time has passed that the seed is effectively unchanged during each call.

That is why, as the other answer mentions, you should only call `srand()` once in your program.

Comment: Ha, that fixed it! If you don't mind, could you explain why moving that to the `main()` function makes this work? I'm assuming it's something about scope, and I don't quite understand why or how "seeding" works.

Comment: @korina The problem is coming because you are re-seeding the random number generator in a very short period of time. The value of time has not changed when you re-seed it. So it again starts from the same random number.

Comment: @korina, Let me update with slightly more details.

Comment: @korina, Updated with more discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You should only be calling `srand()` once in the program, not everytime you want to generate a random number.

If you reseed `rand()` via `time()` in a short succession you'll just end up restarting the sequence and end up getting the first value repeatedly.