# Array elements of a class object are not being set correctly, set() and get() member functions likely cause

Tags: c++, class, oop

This is my first time working with classes in C++ and I seem to be getting tripped up quite a lot. My program is supposed to be a rewrite of a previous program that used struct (see here: [Random number generator in a for loop gives same numbers each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211324/random-number-generator-in-a-for-loop-gives-same-numbers-each-time)), but using a class instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const int WHEEL_POSITIONS = 30;
const char wheelSymbols[WHEEL_POSITIONS + 1] = "-X-X-X-X-X=X=X=X*X*X*X*X@X@X7X";

class slotMachine
{
    private:
        int spinPos;
        char spinSymbol;
    public:
        slotMachine(); // Constructor
        char symbols[WHEEL_POSITIONS + 1]; // Should be private?
        void setSpinSymbol(); // Spins the wheels
        char getSpinSymbol() const // Returns the symbol
            { return spinSymbol; }
} wheels[3];

// Constructor initializes slot wheels to contents of wheelSymbols
slotMachine::slotMachine()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (WHEEL_POSITIONS + 1); j++)
        {
            wheels[i].symbols[j] = wheelSymbols[j];
        }
    }
}

void slotMachine::setSpinSymbol()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        wheels[i].spinPos = (rand() % WHEEL_POSITIONS);
        wheels[i].spinSymbol = wheels[i].symbols[(wheels[i].spinPos)];
    }
}

void displayResults(slotMachine fwheels[3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << fwheels[i].getSpinSymbol();
    }
}

void displayResults(slotMachine []);
//bool getWinner(slotMachine []);

int main(void)
{
    slotMachine wheels[3];
    time_t seed;
    time(&seed);
    srand(seed);

    displayResults(wheels);

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles but outputs the following:

[image]

I have a feeling this error is caused by something having gone amiss in my constructor `slotMachine`, my `getSpinSymbol()` function, or my `setSpinSymbol()` function, but I've looked it over several times and can't seem to figure it out. I've read a handful of material online covering classes in C++, but I'm still very new and very shaky on the concept--apologies if it's something small or obvious that I've overlooked.

Comment: remove wheels[3] from class declaration and use only variable names (without wheels[].) in class functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

```
   1.Class names should be started with upper case letter. slotMachine -> SlotMachine 
   2.Remove wheels[3] after class definition.You are using the array declared in main() method.     
   3.Why you are declaring displayResults(..) again after it's definition?
   4.You are not calling setSpinSymbol() before displayResults(..).
```

Comment: My problem was solved shortly before I saw your comment, but your answer also is best and would have helped me debug my program. Thank you for helping. :)

Comment: C++ doesn't care about how you name things, as long as you use valid characters(first [a-zA-Z_], then [a-zA-Z0-9_]. Myself I prefer slot_machine instead of SlotMachine, but it's only a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was explained to me by a friend not on StackOverflow, and I will transcribe his answer here in case anyone else (for any reason) runs into the same problem:

> You aren't using constructors and methods correctly. You shouldn't be
>   accessing `wheels` (the array of slotMachine objects) directly inside
>   those methods; you should just be performing operations on "this," the
>   slotMachine object on which the method was called. For example, the
>   constructor `slotMachine::slotMachine()` is automatically called for
>   each element of the array wheels. You just need to initialize the
>   current slotMachine object inside the constructor:
>
> ```
> slotMachine::slotMachine()
> {
>     for (int j = 0; j < (WHEEL_POSITIONS + 1); j++)
>     {
>         this->symbols[j] = wheelSymbols[j];
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> And `slotMachine::setSpinSymbol()` should just set the value of
>   spinSymbol for the object on which the method was called:
>
> ```
> void slotMachine::setSpinSymbol()
> {
>     this->spinPos = (rand() % WHEEL_POSITIONS);
>     this->spinSymbol = symbols[this->spinPos];
> }
> ```
>
> (In all of this code, the `this->` part is actually unnecessary; you
>   can leave it out if you want. I put it in to try to make it clearer
>   that these methods are operating on fields of "the current object.")
>
> Now, the reason you are getting garbage is because you never call
>   `setSpinSymbol()`, so the spinSymbol field is never initialized in
>   these objects. You probably want to call `setSpinSymbol()` in the
>   constructor, so that the spinSymbol field is guaranteed to be
>   initialized.

This explanation did solve my problem, and my program now outputs the correct information, so I believe it to be correct. My issues with using constructors and methods correctly has been explained here, and the reason why I was getting garbage values (as well as a few other points) was answered by another commenter.